# What is __prepareLayout Function Return and what is hasData and setData perform ?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, registry, methods

```
public function _prepareLayout()
{
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

And

```
public function getVire()     
 { 
    if (!$this->hasData('vire')) {
        $this->setData('vire', Mage::registry('vire'));
    }
    return $this->getData('vire');

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use magic has*() calls with each class extending Varien_Object to check whether a given property does, or does not exist.

Additionally, Varien_Object offers a non-magic `hasData('property_name')` method.

`set*()` calls with each class extending Varien_Object to set data.

```
setData('test','testvalue')
```

`_prepareLayout();` It collect the xml file lookup and update.
Then accordingly assign the template and finally render.The _prepareLayout() method is called immediately after a block has been added to the layout object for the first time.